# How to extract fasta from a blastdb

Tags: fasta, blast

How to extract the sequence used to create a blast database.  This is useful when you download a blastdb from somewhere else e.g. one of the [databases provided by NCBI](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db) including the 16SMicrobial database. Or alternatively, when you want to double check which version of a sequence you have included in a blastdb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract fasta sequence from a blastdb constructed from a fasta file using blastdbcmd which should be installed when you install blast/makeblastdb.

```
blastdbcmd -entry all -db <database label> -out <outfile>
```

If you had a database called `my_database` which contained the files:

- `my_database.nhr`
- `my_database.nsq`
- `my_database.nin`

and you wanted your fasta output file to be called `reference.fasta` you would run the following:

```
blastdbcmd -entry all -db my_database -out reference.fasta
```